# Fail to InsertAsync() into azure database

Tags: c#, mobile, azure, service, azure-sql-database

I have a problem during inserting data from a mobile app into an azure database.

My table in the database is defined like that:

[image]

This line couse an error:

```
        await usersTable.InsertAsync(
            new User
            {
                FirstName = this.FirstNameTextBox.Text,
                LastName = this.LastNameTextBox.Text,
                DepartmentID = 0,
                LiveID = App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId,
                Level = 0,
                Pluses = 0,
                Minuses = 0,
            });
```

Error message:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cannot insert if the id member is already set.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

And here is a definition of a User class:

```
class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ID")]
    public string LiveID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DepartmentID")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Pluses")]
    public int Pluses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Minuses")]
    public int Minuses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the id column could be anything but int or bigint, but check out this thread:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/18196872-6b47-4bf6-bbe6-85f0e1e2e573/id-field-in-windows-azure-mobile-service   Perhaps changing the JsonProperty PropertyName attribute to lower case "id" (and recreating the table) will help?

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem, in my case, during debug, I found that I was inserting an entry with the same unique identifier, you can try this direction, and check for duplication before insert.